# What's the difference between PyUno and PyUno Bridge?

Tags: pyuno

What's the difference between PyUno and PyUno Bridge?  Or are they two names for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are a bit different?

Reading the documentation for which I'll leave links below, I can conclude that Uno is the interface based component model of Apache OpenOffice, and it has a binding to it under the name of "Py-UNO", while PyUno Bridge is the connection that the UNO establishes with the Apache OpenOffice API when developing UNO components. Therefore PyUNO Bridge has been named as the process of using this PyUno model.

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_bridge

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno